# AWS S3 upload not working after converting from callback to Async-Await format using Promisify

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, promise, aws-sdk

I'm using [upload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#upload-property) method from [aws-sdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk) to upload files to S3 bucket from React app in browser.

The [original callback based upload method](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#upload-property) is as bellow:

```
var params = {Bucket: 'bucket', Key: 'key', Body: stream};
s3.upload(params, function(err, data) {
  console.log(err, data);
});
```

I wrapped it with [promisify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-promisify) to work it like Async-await as bellow:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const { promisify } = require('es6-promisify');

... <in my React component> ...
async uploadFile() {
try {
    var params = {
      Bucket: <BucketName>,
      Key: <KeyName>,
      Body: <File Stream>
    };
    const res = await uploadToS3Async(params);
    console.log(res);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

Now when I'm calling `uploadFile` function on some event fired it produces following error:

```
TypeError: service.getSignatureVersion is not a function
    at ManagedUpload.bindServiceObject  
    at ManagedUpload.configure 
    at new ManagedUpload  
    at upload   
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
```

Comment: There is no `getSignatureVersion ` in the code you provided.

Comment: there isn't even a `service`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't need to use `es6-promisify`

You can do:

```
try {
  const params = {Bucket: 'bucket', Key: 'key', Body: stream};  
  const data = await s3.upload(params).promise();
  console.log(data);
}
catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
}
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/using-promises.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make it a `Promisify`, Then you can simply achieve like this

**aws.js**

```
const params = {
    Bucket: 'bucket',
    Key: 'key',
    Body: stream
};

const awsService = {};

awaService.upload = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        s3.upload(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            }
            return resolve(data);
        });
    });
};

module.exports = awsService;
```

On another file just call like this

**util.js**

```
const awsService = require('./awsService');

const utils = {};

utils.upload = async () => {
    try {
        const result = await awsService.upload();
        return result;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        throw err;
    }
};

module.exports = utils;
```